# windows phone tap gesture location

Tags: c#, windows-phone, gesture

how can I go about getting the location on for example a image, where exactly on the image the user touches. example if I have a map as an image, and the user touches Africa, I want get the specific location of the tap so I can handle it in code behind.

What API's can I use for this any examples?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Capture the Tap event on the image, and the event args will give you the position. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff426933(v=vs.95).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.uielement.tap(v=vs.95).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs(v=VS.95).aspx